# Clone void* pointer to int

Tags: c, pointers, clone

I have this signature of a function:

```
void* cloneInt(const void* i);
```

This `int` represents a key for a hash function. I need to have this clone function as it is in my API for a generic implementation of a hash table (this function is a part of the int implementation, this function will be forwarded as a pointer to a function that my generic implementation will use). 
But I am having a problem understanding: how can you clone an `int`? I need to return a pointer that will point on the same value of `int`, but a different place in the memory. This got me very much confused.

Comment: You allocate memory for an `int` and store `*i` there?

Comment: Will this work? void* cloneInt(const void* i)
{
    int myInt = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    myInt = *i; 
    return &myInt;
}

Comment: No it won't, you need to create `int* myInt`, and you need to assign it with `*myInt = *i`.

Comment: And when i want to free this int, should i free(myInt) or free(*myInt)? Should i free the pointer or the int itself?

Comment: I believe you should consult http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/11683 before going any further @Eyzuky.

Comment: I all depends on how you designed the map. Who's responsible for allocating memory for the keys & objects stored, the map or the user? And When freeing it?

Comment: Why does a function called `cloneInt` accept/return a pointer to `void`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth OP said "_I need to have this clone function as it is in my API for a generic implementation of a hash table_"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* cloneInt(const void* i)
{
    int *myInt = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *myInt = *(int*)i;
    return myInt;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i=10;
    int *j;
    j = cloneInt(&i);
    printf("j: %d i: %d\n", *j, i);
    free(j);
}
```